# QField elevation receives Ellipsoidal elevation only from Trimble Catalyst DA1 via USB Connection - Orthometric not possible

Tags: qfield

**SOFTWARE VERSION IN USE:**
Using QGIS (V 3.16.11 LTR); QField (V 1.9.6 - latest) and Trimble Catalyst GNNS Antenna / Trimble Mobile Manager (V 2.9.0 - latest).
**QFIELD SETUP:**
Qfield receives RTK GNSS data via USB cable connection to Trimble TDS600 Android mobile device, using mock location run through Trimble Mobile Manager.  Trimble Mobile Manager reports both Ellipsoidal and Orthometric elevation - see link: https://geospatial.trimble.com/blog/trimble-mobile-manager-adds-orthometric-height-support-geodetic-functionality  QField set to collect Point elevation data via Expression: z(start_point($geometry)) from Trimble Mobile Manager.  QFIELD set up with Vertical Grid Shift Geoid09_V1.01.gsb in Folder: /QField/proj as suggested in documentation. Both Skip altitude correction enable and disable have been tried with no change in elevation (Ellipsoidal value reported in both cases).

**PROBLEM / RESULTS:**
Elevation (Z) data field only populated with Ellipsoidal height, even when altitude correction is selected with Vertical grid shift of AUSGeoid09_V1.01.gsb in the correct folder on the mobile device.  This is a USB connection (NOT BLUETOOTH) - is this the problem when expecting a Bluetooth data stream sequence for elevation?  Similar issue discussed in LINK: https://apac01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fopengisch%2FQField%2Fissues%2F1601&data=04%7C01%7C%7Ca3c13deb8a654af8de9c08d994fc6431%7C84df9e7fe9f640afb435aaaaaaaaaaaa%7C1%7C0%7C637704634019952068%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=Iu7O%2BXx4KxgYK8EVLLbnSEyurfax9iGcE0GFRirEfaE%3D&reserved=0
This discussion list Field 9 as Orthometric and Field 11 as Ellipsoidal for Bluetooth conneceted devices.  No mention of USB connection.

**EXPECTED RESULT:**
When applying the Vertical Grid Shift (AUDGeoid09) I would expect Ellipsoidal elevation from Trimble Mobile Manager to be converted to Orthographic using the specified Geoid and written to QFields "z" co-ordinate field / shown in the co-ordinate data on screen.

Any pointers? This is fantastic software and easy to use (better than the competition) and accurate elevation data inclusion is already setup (via bluetooth device connection) - but is this also available via USB connected GNSS external device?

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, not being a user of that software, the AUSGeiod09 GSB is in GDA94 but perhaps your Easting/Northing is in an incompatible datum (WGS84 or GDA2020 for example). Are you recording your X,Y in GDA2020/MGA2020? Perhaps the AUSGeoid2020 would work better, it's only a few centimetres different in most areas which is minuscule compared with the Z accuracy of non-differential GPS units.

Comment: Hi Michael, I am using the GDA94 datum for the layer in QGIS, so the Geoid should be compatible.  The Z difference b/w Ellipsoid and Orthometric in this part of the world should be approx 15m.  I am not seeing any adjustment to Ellipsoid height when I apply the Geoid - as if QField is simply not getting the required data.  Thanks for your time - I will just have to hope someone knows how QField calls on the Geoid calculation wrt external device input via USB.  Cheers

Comment: Did you select the grid shift under settings -> positioning? The documentation is a bit short on this point. An improvement is being proposed here: https://github.com/opengisch/QField-docs/pull/155/files please do not hesitate to comment or improve the documentation with any other missing or wrong points.

Comment: Thanks for your response Matthias - I did select the Grid Shift option and have the AUSGeoid09_V1.01.gsb file available in the prj folder on the device.  Using the  "skip altitude correction" toggle while having the vertical grid shift in use makes no difference in the Orthometric elevation - Ellipsoid still reported.    Is there a difference in the GNSS data field order between Bluetooth and USB streams from an external GNSS source that may not trigger the vertical grid shift?  Many thanks for your assistance - greatly appreciated.  Dean